# Get ROLLUP to include rows for missing values

Tags: postgresql, group-by, left-join, rollup, cross-join

PostgreSQL 14

Assuming this sample data:

| fruit | ripeness |
| --- | --- |
| orange | 1 |
| orange | 3 |
| apple | 0 |
| apple | 3 |
| apple | 3 |
| apple | 2 |

Is there a way to get ROLLUP to give me a count of fruits by ripeness with a row for each possible value of ripeness like this:

| fruit | ripeness | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 0 | 0 |
| orange | 1 | 1 |
| orange | 2 | 0 |
| orange | 3 | 1 |
| orange |  | 2 |
| apple | 0 | 1 |
| apple | 1 | 0 |
| apple | 2 | 1 |
| apple | 3 | 2 |
| apple |  | 4 |
|  |  | 6 |

Instead of only the existing values in the group appearing like this:

| fruit | ripeness | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 1 | 1 |
| orange | 3 | 1 |
| orange |  | 2 |
| apple | 0 | 1 |
| apple | 2 | 1 |
| apple | 3 | 2 |
| apple |  | 4 |
|  |  | 6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join the distinct values of `fruit` to the distinct values of `ripeness` and do a `LEFT` join to the table.
Then aggregate with `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT f.fruit, r.ripeness, 
       COUNT(t.fruit) counter
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM tablename) f
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ripeness FROM tablename) r
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON t.fruit = f.fruit AND t.ripeness = r.ripeness
GROUP BY ROLLUP(f.fruit, r.ripeness)
ORDER BY f.fruit, r.ripeness;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1134724db492bfc3a3e1fba493e06105).

Comment: That works. How ugly does it get if I have three groups, i.e. fruit, ripeness, quality?

Comment: @EMF for this you would need another cross join with the distinct qualities.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without `ROLLUP`, naive but intuitive:

```sql
select * from (
  (
    select distinct f1.fruit, f2.ripeness, (
        select count(1) from fruit fsq where
            f1.fruit = fsq.fruit and
            f2.ripeness = fsq.ripeness
    ) from fruit f1
    left join fruit f2 on true
    group by f1.fruit, f2.ripeness
  )
  union
  (
  select fruit.fruit, null, count(1) from fruit
    group by fruit.fruit
  )
  union
  (
  select null, null, count(1) from fruit
  )
) mq
order by 1, 2;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pZE4FhQJp6aWBTTB2VSoua/0).

Comment: I need to use ROLLUP for reasons not shown in the simplified example